# Can't access IP addresses on my local network with VPN and ufw enabled

Tags: networking, vpn, ufw

As of today I am not able to access IP addresses on my local network on Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday everything was fine, obviously some updates went through and messed things up. I am using a native VPN client and I have ufw enabled with the firewall's default settings:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

Disabling VPN or ufw makes my local network accessable. It seems I need to set up a specific rule for the VPN interface, tried `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24` without any luck.

I would like to set up a strict rule allowing me to access a particular IP address on my network, let's say 192.168.1.1 when my VPN is running and ufw is enabled. Thanks.

edit: Here's the `grep UFW /var/log/syslog` output:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp5s0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

edit2: Here's the `/var/log/apt/history.log` output:

```
Start-Date: 2020-06-25  09:17:29
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: XYZ (1000)
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-37.41, 5.4.0-39.43), libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1), curl:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1), libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1)
End-Date: 2020-06-25  09:17:32

Start-Date: 2020-06-25  09:19:34
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.126'
Install: linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-39.43, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-39:amd64 (5.4.0-39.43, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-39.43, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-39.43, automatic), linux-modules-5.4.0-39-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-39.43, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.37.40, 5.4.0.39.42), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.37.40, 5.4.0.39.42), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0.37.40, 5.4.0.39.42)
End-Date: 2020-06-25  09:20:12
```

Comment: Hmmm. Kernel update. Verify, please: If you reboot into an older kernel at GRUB, it works again?

Comment: Well, about that...sigh. After running my machine for half a day I did not notice any issues and decided to tidy things up with autoremove and autoclean. Stupid, I know.

Comment: Check at GRUB - the kernel postinst script keeps at least one older kernel. Autoremove/autoclean will still leave you that one older kernel. In order to file a useful bug report, you need to be able to demonstrate that the ONLY change was booting into a different kernel.